# remap Caps + L to dash

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to remap the four keys `()-=` to `Caps+jkl;` respectively.
The idea is to not leave the home row for typing these characters which are very common in programming.

This includes pressing `Caps Shift l` to produce `_`, which is the equivalent of `Shift -`

I also want `Caps` to act as `ESC` when pressed on it's own.

What I've tried already:

1. https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor - Installation has syntax error
2. https://www.bedroomlan.org/projects/evrouter/ - No support for multi keys
3. editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` - I don't see an option for combinations, and couldnn't figure it out from the [docs](https://michal.kosmulski.org/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html)
4. [evdevremapkeys](https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys) - no support as described in [this issue](https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys/issues/4)
5. `xdotool` - works but it's very slow ...
6. Mapping directly in `vim` - that would be my fallback, tho I want this available system-wide

Any help appreciated, probably some guidance would be enough for me to crack this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Check xmodmap to change keyboard layout.

Comment: isn't it [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122151/xmodmap-problems-and-inconsistencies-with-more-than-4-alternative-symbols-per-ke)?

Comment: Interesting read. You may want to make an answer of this. Still, xmodmap may be sufficient to just swap some keys as indicated in the commands. I have no experience. Otherwise I would have written an answer.

Comment: Are you using caps as an actual capslock or have you remapped it to something like ctrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Work Around***

***Warning: editing the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` is very risky if any small typo mistakes occur.. it leads to login loop.. Proceed only if you can manage things from tty in such case..***

1. change directory to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`

run command:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

2. take backup of `us` file

run command:

```
sudo cp us usbackup
```

3. edit the file `us`

run command:

```
sudo -H gedit us
```

4. Edit the lines like below

Content:

```
key <AC01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
key <AC03> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
key <AC04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
key <AC05> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
key <AC07> {    [     j,    J,  parenleft           ]   };
key <AC08> {    [     k,    K,  parenright          ]   };
key <AC09> {    [     l,    L,  minus, underscore   ]   };
key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon,  equal,  plus]   };
key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl            ]   };
```

5. Save the file and Close.
6. gnome-shell refresh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or Logout & Login may be required..not tested..
7. make Caps_Lock as the level3 modifier with the below command

run command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:caps_switch']"
```

with the above command the `Caps_Lock` modifier changed to `ISO_Level3_Shift` which will print the 3rd keysym from the edited `us` file while Caps_Lock is held down.. similarly 4th keysym if Caps_Lock & Shift are held down..

8. Now to make the modifier ISO_Level3_Shift to behave on its own while pressed and released.. use the great tool `xcape`..

run command:

```
sudo apt install xcape
```

> Description: Configure modifier keys to act as other keys when pressed
>   and released  xcape allows you to use a modifier key as another key
>   when pressed and  released on its own.  Note that it is slightly
>   slower than pressing the  original key, because the pressed event does
>   not occur until the key is  released.  The default behaviour is to
>   generate the Escape key when Left  Control is pressed and released on
>   its own.

9. once xcape is installed run the below command to make Caps_Lock behave as Escape when it is pressed and released..

run command:

```
xcape -e 'ISO_Level3_Shift=Escape'
```

10. Add the above command in your startup applications preference list so that no need to run the command on every login/ boot..

[image]

[image]

thats it.. You are Done..

---

with the Caps_Lock Modifier all the 4 things `(` `)` `-` `=` and with Caps_Lock+Shift Modifiers `_` are achieved..

When only Caps_Lock is pressed and released.. It acted as Escape as that is how we configured.

[image]

Comment: can I use this in a way that doesn't disables the caps key when pressed on it's own? Because I want to map it to `ESC` if pressed alone, and to other things (like `()-+`) when pressed with another key. Also, with this solution pressing `caps+shift+l` doesn't type underscore. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure! I edited the question as you asked. I now see that this solution doesn't work on vim :/ for the 4th level, what would be inside the parens `leve4(???)` ?

Comment: thanks, and how do I include the level 4? Also, what about the other issues? This doesn't work in vim, which is the main use case

Comment: interesting it works for you  In anyway, I need a solution that doesn't disables the caps lock key on it's own, as I stated in the previous comments. If I press the capslock key by itself, I want it mapped to the ESC key.

Comment: you, sir, are a GENIUS!!!! This opens up so many possibilities YOU HAVE NO IDEA. THANK YOU @PRATAP !!!!!!!!!