# add accented character to american keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am using GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 19.04 and have a US keyboard and I would like to add the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> = <kbd>é</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> = <kbd>ö</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> = <kbd>à</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> = <kbd>ä</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> = <kbd>è</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> = <kbd>ü</kbd>

and I need to set <kbd>y</kbd> as <kbd>z</kbd> and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following the below posts and warnings in it.. proceed with your own..

[remap Caps + L to dash](https://askubuntu.com/q/1160465/739431)
[Keyboard (including on screen keyboard) doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/1176777/739431)

you need to edit your symbols like below in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` after taking backup of the same..

```
key <AD06> {    [     z,    Z       ]   };
key <AD07> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
key <AD08> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
key <AD09> {    [     o,    O       ]   };
key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft, egrave, udiaeresis   ]   };
key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

key <AC01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
key <AC03> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
key <AC04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
key <AC05> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
key <AC07> {    [     j,    J       ]   };
key <AC08> {    [     k,    K       ]   };
key <AC09> {    [     l,    L       ]   };
key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon,  eacute, odiaeresis  ]   };
key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl, agrave, adiaeresis    ]   };

key <AB01> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
```

gnome-shell refresh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or Logout & Login may be required..not tested..

then you need to choose which key is for level3 from "gnome-tweaks" or via "dconf-editor" or via "command line"

Gnome-Tweaks way
[image]

Dconf-Editor way
[image]

Command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_switch']"
```